# Hibernate throws error after migration (references on same collection)

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a problem with using a OneToMany-Mapping with Hibernate that was working in version 4.3.8.Final but is not with version 5.4.2.Final .

When I query multiple entities from the db that have the same entries in a list that is mapped with OneToMany and then try to update those entities, hibernate throws the following exception even though I do not update any entries from the mapped relation: "Found shared reference to a collection: de.Artikel.filialeLager; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared reference to a collection: de.Artikel.filialeLager"

Here is my mapping, that was working fine with version 4.3.8.Final of Hibernate but is not anymore with 5.4.2.Final.:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", referencedColumnName="SOME_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<filialeLager> filialeLager;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have a unidirectional relationship but is adding a reference column for a two-way relationship

> The name of the column referenced by this foreign key column. When
>   used with entity relationship mappings other than the cases described
>   below, the referenced column is in the table of the target entity.
>   When used with a unidirectional OneToMany foreign key mapping, the
>   referenced column is in the table of the source entity. When used
>   inside a Join- Table annotation, the referenced key column is in the
>   entity table of the owning entity, or inverse entity if the join is
>   part of the inverse join definition. When used in a collection table
>   mapping, the referenced column is in the table of the entity
>   containing the collection.

You should have something similar to this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "SOME_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private List<filialeLager> filialeLager;
```

Comment: I think I need the _referencedColumnName_-Parameter because SOME_ID is not part of the primary key in one of the tables that are part of the relation. Without this parameter objects of _filialeLager_ are not mapped correctly.

Comment: @JSchubert please edit your question and add the entities to know what relationship you want to do and what are your identifiers

Comment: I found the problem. The OneToMany-Mapping is wrong. The Database has a ManyToMany-Relation. I have no idea why this mapping worked with version 4.3.8.